# rails assets not being compiled into one file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ./includes
//= require global
```

My layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spectrum</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
...
```

My config/environments/development.rb file:

```
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = false
```

However, when I load the page in a browser, all the js and css files are still being loaded separately:

```
<head>
  <title>Title!</title>


    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/utility.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/charting.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/global.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/questions.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/includes/includes.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="kZEkjHQ/7PQ3zn95MJnHi0JJUk6b6b+6N2Uwejr3y6g=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

Comment: are you development mode? If so thats ok, it's supposed to happen like that, it doesn't change until you get to production

Comment: stephenmurdoch is right.  try `rails s production` and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed... had to restart server and that's all ><

Answer (score 1):

From the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development)

> In development mode assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file.

Comment: Oh, even if I turn off the debugging? Did http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off lie to me?

Comment: oh, crap, you're right, my bad, read your question too quick. I don't suppose you have something like `javascript_include_tag 'application', :debug=> true` in your layout cos that would override what you're doing in `development.rb`

Comment: No my layout is `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: I have to restart the server ><

Comment: did you restart your server? You need to if you change that file

Answer (score 1):

It must be `rails s -e production` in current rails version to start server in production mode.